# Trying to run WCF web service on non-domain VM, Security Errors

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, wcf-security

Am I in a Catch-22 situation here? My goal is to take a WCF service that I inherited, and run it on a VM and test it by calling it from my desktop PC.  The VM is in a workgroup, and not in the company's domain.  Basically, we need more test environments, ideally one per developer (we may have 2 to 4 people that need this).  Thus the idea of the VM was that each developer could have his own web server that somewhat matches or real environment (where we actually have two websites, an external/exposed and internal). 
[Using VS2010 .NET 4.0]

In the internal service, each method was decorated with this attribute:

```
 [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
```

I'm still researching why this was needed. I think it's because a webapp calls the "internal" service, and either a) we need the credentials of the user, or b) we may doing some PrinciplePermission.Demands to see if the user is in a group.  My interest is creating some ConsoleTest programs or UnitTest programs.

I changed to allowed like this:

```
 [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
```

because I was getting this error in trying to view the .svc in the browser:

The contract operation 'EditAccountFamily' requires Windows identity for automatic impersonation. A Windows identity that represents the caller is not provided by binding ('WSHttpBinding','http://tempuri.org/') for contract ('IAdminService','http://tempuri.org/'.

I don't get that error with the original bindings look like this:

However, I believe I need to turn off this security since the web service is not on the domain.

I tend to get these errors in the client:

1) The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed - as an InnerException of "SecurityNegotiation was unhandled".

or

2) The caller was not authenticated by the service as an InnerException of "SecurityNegotiation was unhandled".

So can I create some configuration of code and web.config that will allow each developer to work on his own VM?  Or must I join the VM to the domain?

The number of permutations seems near endless. I've started to create a Word.doc that says what to do with each error, but now I'm in the catch-22 where I'm stuck.

Thanks,

Neal

---

Server Bindings:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding
      name="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000">
      <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="2147483647"
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <!-- <security mode="None" />  This is one thing I tried --> 
      <security>
        <message
          clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>


    <behavior
      name="ABC.AdminService.AdminServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and 
           remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata
        httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  
           Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug
        includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <!--<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" 
            roleProviderName="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>-->
      <serviceAuthorization
        principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups"
        impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>


<serviceHostingEnvironment
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

CLIENT:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IAdminService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.159.132/EC_AdminService/AdminService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAdminService"
            contract="svcRef.IAdminService" name="WSHttpBinding_IAdminService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Update 12/27/2010: 
Even this simple method gets SecurityNegotiation Error:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
public string TestHelloWorldOpen(string name)
{
    return "Hello1 " + name;
}
```

Comment: Please post your client and server bindings.

Comment: Is putting the VM's on the domain out of the question? If I had a personal test server, I'd want it on the domain, especially if I was using Windows authentication for anything. You'll probably be fighting similar problems with other applications as well.

Comment: @Aaron - That's what I'm thinking, it has to be on domain, but what other apps might you be referring to?  No, it's not out of the question, just more politics, firewalls, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the security elements from both the server and client bindings.

The problem might be due to a mismatch between the server and client security element.  Usually when something goes wrong with WCF, it's because of an error in the binding configurations.  A good troubleshooting strategy is to remove all unnecessary configuration elements and then try to add them back in one by one - thus isolating the problem.

Comment: That's kind of the approach that's got me nowhere for a few days, thus I decided to post here.  Commenting out <security> tags in both resulted in pretty much same: Exception: {"The caller was not authenticated by the service."} Inner:{"The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed."}

Comment: If the program has  [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
 on each method - then how could we turn security off?  You cannot impersonate if you don't pass some user right?  Thus the catch-22 concept I was referring to.

Comment: I thought you had it set to Impersonation.Allowed?  There's no catch-22 here, I have WCF set up using impersonation on a workgroup - no problems.  What happens if you set Impersonation.Allowed?

Comment: @Neal: This might seem obvious, but is the UserName of the client also a UserName on the server machine?  This is required for NTLM to work.

Answer (score 0):

You stated in your question:

> ...the idea of the VM was that each
>   developer could have his own web
>   server that somewhat matches our real
>   environment.

My point is that you are going to have issues like this with every application you put on that VM that uses Windows authentication until you put it on the domain. I don't see this as a WCF specific issue. It's an issue of trusting credentials from a non-trusted domain. Plus, I'm assuming that your real environment is on a domain, so to really match environments your VM's should be on a domain as well.

(reply from comment): I just assumed that you may have more than one application. I could be wrong. But you'd be having this issue if you were using Windows authentication with ASP.NET.

The least ideal situation is to have custom code in your applications and services just to get them to run in a special test/dev environment.